# Vim set columns not working

Tags: vim

On Ubuntu 12.04

```
:version
VIM - Vi IMproved 7.3 (2010 Aug 15, compiled May  4 2012 04:22:36)
Included patches: 1-429
```

`:set columns=84` has no effect as after it `:set columns?` gives 151. Why setting columns is not respected by vim?

Comment: What term are you using? Maybe your terminal doesn't support resizing.

Comment: `echo $TERM` says xterm

Comment: Any terminal application may claim to be `xterm`. What's the actual terminal application you are using?

Comment: didnt he ask term? anyways, Gnome Terminal 3.4.1.1

Answer (score 0):

```
if exists('+colorcolumn')
  set colorcolumn=80
else
  au BufWinEnter * let w:m2=matchadd('ErrorMsg', '\%>80v.\+', -1)
endif
```

Comment: How does this answer the question? columns and colorcolumn are two different settings.